# Facebook Like to section of website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm developing a website with some sections, and i need to count different "LIKES" for each section.
I'm trying to do it by graph api with javascript, and i figured how to make a post like this

```
FB.login(function(){
   FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'i just post this'});
}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

but i don't know how to do a "LIKE". What i need is to make CUSTOME LIKE BUTTON for example to www.example.com?1 and "LIKE" to www.example.com?2 etc etc

Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) you just need to add the page url.

Comment: I can't customize a button with my own image with that way. :s i need to put my own like image

Comment: I am sure that there are ways to change the icon but its not advisable because its against FB's T&C. read more details here https://www.facebookbrand.com/guidelines?asset=5&media=1,2,3&platform=0